# Non-greedy NSRegularExpression

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm need an NSRegularExpression that matches non-greedily. You know, if there's:

```
ABABABA
```

...and I ask it to match `B.*B` I want it to grab the SMALLEST possible match: `BAB`, not `BABAB`.

I've been googling this for an hour now, and I keep finding references to the ICU/XCode regex implementation having support for non-greedy matching, but for the life of me, I can't find the syntax to actually do it anywhere.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add the question mark:

```
B.*?B
```

See table 2 in the [reference of NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: The same non-greedy regex works for xcode "find and replace"